# Did Hitler only have one testicle?

Tags: adolf-hitler

It has been suggested many times that [Adolf Hitler suffered from monorchism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler%27s_possible_monorchism) - i.e. he had only one testicle. Amusingly, people always seem to remember that it was (supposedly) his left testicle that was missing.

The Wikipedia article is pretty verbose and has numerous issues, and I couldn't spot anything definitive on Snopes, so I'm not quite sure where this one stands. Some suggest that it was a rumour started to boost British morale, others suggest that autopsy notes proved it to be true.

Can anyone provide a definitive, or at least comprehensive, answer?

<sub>Foot-note: I really am surprised that nobody has asked this on here yet!</sub>

Comment: Nah he definately had 2, but if I remember correctly, the other was relocated to the Albert Hall.

Comment: Note that claiming a physical defect (the more grotesque and/or delicate the better) of the enemy leader is an effective tool of propaganda since time immemorial (most likely literally so - older than written records, that is).

Comment: I remember singing [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler_Has_Only_Got_One_Ball) (Variant 3) in the bus on school trips :)

Comment: There was also an ITMA sketch about the predicament of "Funf" (a German spy) tasked with uncovering the words to "Colonel Bogey" and making his report direct to the Fuhrer...

Comment: According to reliable sources (rowdy British army songs), Hitler indeed only had one ball.  Goreing had two, but very small.  Himler was somewhat similar and Goebels had no balls at all.

Comment: I read somewhere (don't remember where) that there was an extant physical examination report by a doctor that described his genitals as normal.  Best I have.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like Skeptics.SE, The Straight Dope column by Cecil Adams looks at urban myths and investigates the evidence.

Back in 1987, The Straight Dope looked at this question: [Did Hitler have only one testicle?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/881/did-hitler-have-only-one-testicle)

The conclusion reached was less than definitive:

- The idea was recorded in insulting ditties sung during World War II.
- A British historian determined that he and Eva Braun shot themselves and were cremated without autopsy.
- The Russians initially maintained he escaped.
- In 1950, the Russians claimed they had taken poison and then buried. Later still, they claimed that his remains had been exhumed, and an autopsy performed.
- A book published in 1968 with purported autopsy results claimed that he was missing a left testicle, even though none of his medical records or doctor's reports mention it.
- The autopsy was later pronounced genuine by an American dental expert in 1972.

All up, the evidence found by Cecil Adams seems rather dubious. He is a talented researcher. This suggests (but doesn't prove) that there isn't (or at least wasn't) any quality evidence in either direction.